# CouchDB: Re-running a completed replication progressing slowly

Tags: couchdb, database-replication

I wrote a service which does the following on startup:

1. Boots up CouchDB
2. Makes a pull _replicate (+continuous) request to CouchDB
3. Monitors _active_tasks for the 'progress' to reach 100 before considering itself as ready

However, the database I'm dealing with is fairly large and so the replication task takes a very long time to reach 100 even though I only turned off the database recently, and it had a continuous replication task before that, so it should be almost entirely up to date. That is, the incremental replication should be quick.

Why could it be taking so long considering it's already almost up to date, and is there anything I can do to either speed it up OR allow my service to consider itself as ready before "progress" reaches 100? The latter seems unlikely as I do want it to be fully up to date.

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you still having this issue? I'm having a problem where 'progress' in _active_tasks is stuck on 98. I was wondering if you were having a  similar issue.

Comment: @vandervault, it seems to be a different issue, but I haven't answered my question yet -- we just no longer need it to fully sync before starting the service, so it's okay that it takes a while. It does reach 100% eventually though.